# Is there a workaround to importing foreign schema's functions in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

My use case is that I would like to use a function from one database server into a schema of the DB i am operating in. From it looks like, foreign data wrapper only supports importing tables and when I do-

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA foreign_schema FROM SERVER foreign_server INTO temp_schema
```

I don't really see the functions getting imported.

Is there a way I could get the functions imported as well? or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) for this, to execute any piece of SQL on the remote server, including function calls.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to use the imported function (on the remote server) in a function that already exists in my DB. Can dblink solve for that?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap a dblink call to the remote server, in a local function.